# windows.location is adding the old path with new one

Tags: javascript

I have a page login.aspx, it has a link `<a href= "webfolder/abc.aspx"`
on click it opens properly but when i open another link which is on abc.aspx,
link `<a href = "webfolder/abc1.aspx">` this one does not opens instead.
it copies `webfolder/webfolder/abc1.aspx` in url twoice.

```
  I wanted to understand the behaviour. what is it and how and why it is doing.
```

and then I want to solve the above problem.

Comment: Change to <a href= "/webfolder/abc.aspx">

Comment: Where does JavaScript come into play? Looks just like plain HTML.

Comment: It's because you have a _relative_ URL. Check out "examples of relative URLs" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL to understand the behavior

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the first link is referring to webfolder, if you click again in a link with another folder, you will redirected to that folder to.
What you have to do is redirect with a dash. Example:

```
<a href= "/webfolder/abc.aspx">

<a href = "/webfolder/abc1.aspx">
```

Comment: I know that, adding  / to the URL works, in fact we have used this only, but i removed it while exprementing, so that it can work with some prox server and we need to add the locaiton of proxy server (nginx) to our path. so in short pls find some solution where I do not have to put "/" in front of the path. or if there is any common place where we can intercept the call and put the "/" with other path like "PTK/JBL" in front of the path  "/webfolder/abc1.aspx", etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

in global.asax, the response code of response.redirect could be intercepted and there we could append "ptk/jbl", and it is commonplace to do it.